# Keep nulls during df.loc

Tags: sql, pandas

In the following statement: `df_clean = df.loc[df['time'] < upper_bound]` I remove outliers (`upper_bond`) from function.
However, the output removes all nulls from `df`- which I need to keep.

Is there an alternative way to write this to keep the nulls?

Comment: `df_clean = df.loc[(df['time'] < upper_bound) | (df['time'].isnull())]` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter on multiple conditions, you can `or` them using the unary `|` operator and enclose the conditions using parentheses `()` due to operator precedence.

```
df_clean = df.loc[(df['time'] < upper_bound) | (df['time'].isnull())]
```

So here we add the condition `isnull` to include `NaN` or `NaT` values in the resultant filtered df.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_clean = df.loc[(df['time'] < upper_bound) | (df["time"].isnull())]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.